# SOAP Service: Missing WS-Addressing header

Tags: soap, netbeans, service, glassfish, java-metro-framework

I have a Netbeans SOAP service I can deploy with no issues and a Silverlight client.

When I call the service from Silverlight, I get (in silverlight):

```
new DiscourseParserWSClient created;
event handler added;
service called; Service State is: Open
http://localhost:8080/DiscourseParserWS/DiscourseParserWSService
An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. 
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

After the client calls the service, GlassFish v3 Domain responds with the following problem I fail to decipher:

```
WARNING: A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present, Problem header:{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action
com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.model.MissingAddressingHeaderException: Missing WS-Addressing header: "{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action"
        at com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.WsaTube.checkCardinality(WsaTube.java:235)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.WsaTube.checkMessageAddressingProperties(WsaTube.java:183)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.WsaServerTube.checkMessageAddressingProperties(WsaServerTube.java:281)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.WsaTube.validateInboundHeaders(WsaTube.java:140)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.WsaServerTube.processRequest(WsaServerTube.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:195)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:127)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:515)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:147)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I'm using Metro 2.1 and after quite some googling I suspect the problem might have something to do with it...

I can see the service's wsdl so I believe it can't be an implementation problem. But that warning's stack goes down to the Thread class o.O?

```
public void run() {
if (target != null) {
    target.run(); // <-- to this line to be exact
}
}
```

Please help shed some light; I already have a couple of eclipse soap services working with this client, but I don't have experience with Netbeans, GlassFish and Metro and can't figure out what's causing this...

Comment: I was receiving the same WARNING http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306108/java-missing-ws-addressing-header-http-www-w3-org-2005-08-addressingaction

Answer (score 4):

Don't know whether or not it is too late, but it helped me sometimes to add the

> @Addressing(enabled=true,
>   required=false)

to the WebService (class annotation). Then the exception usually disappears.

For some more information about the addressing stuff you can refer to [1](http://blogs.oracle.com/artf/entry/using_jax_ws_2_1).

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving the same WARNING and thought this might help someone else.

If you're using the "Reliable Message Delivery" option in Netbeans visual web service designer then you may get this warning.

If you don't require the "Reliable Message Delivery" you can simply turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue today and the problem was resolved by using the Action attribute on the soap header. I have confirmed this using SoapUI.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mal="http://example.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
   <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:2c7ea154-668e-4c8b-abaa-8b119f91b8dd</MessageID>
   <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://example.com/input</Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      ......
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If we arent passing the Action attribute than we get error message:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Header>
      <FaultDetail xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
         <ProblemHeaderQName>{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action</ProblemHeaderQName>
      </FaultDetail>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <faultcode xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">wsa:MessageAddressingHeaderRequired</faultcode>
         <faultstring>A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The value of Action header is determined from @Action on the webmethod.

```
@Action(input = "http://example.com/input", output = "http://example.com/output")
```