# Java-Missing WS-Addressing header: "{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action"

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

I try to client to web service in java 7. I get it:

WARNING: A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present, Problem header:{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.addressing.model.MissingAddressingHeaderException: Missing WS-Addressing header: "{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action"

How can I solve this error?

Thanks a lot.

--web service security looks like following parts in SOAPUI--

```
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>gelistirici</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">gelistirme12</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">NT357!!_</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2016-05-07T11:57:03.821Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

--Web Service Interface--

```
 @WebMethod(action = "getRequestDetail")
    @WebResult(name = "requestDetail", targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getRequestDetail", targetNamespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/scheduler", className = "tr.com.service.soap.client.oracle.ess.beans.GetRequestDetail")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getRequestDetailResponse", targetNamespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/scheduler", className = "tr.com.service.soap.client.oracle.ess.beans.GetRequestDetailResponse")
    public RequestDetail getRequestDetail(
        @WebParam(name = "requestId", targetNamespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/scheduler")
       long requestId)
        throws NotFoundException_Exception, RuntimeServiceException_Exception;
```

--java code for web service client--

```
ESSWebService_Service service = new ESSWebService_Service();
  ESSWebService port = service.getSchedulerServiceImplPort();
  BindingProvider provider = BindingProvider.class.cast(port);

  provider.getRequestContext().put("UsernameToken", "UsernameToken-1");
  provider.getRequestContext().put("Username", "gelistirici");
  provider.getRequestContext().put("Password", "gelistirme12");
  provider.getRequestContext().put("Nonce", "NT357!!_");
  provider.getRequestContext().put("Created", "2016-05-07T11:57:03.821Z");

  RequestDetail requestDetail = port.getRequestDetail(37);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this error: "A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present" . Things to do in this case: add above part to class that implement `<SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`

```
@Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        Set<QName> set = new HashSet<QName>();
        set.add(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "Action"));
        return set;
    }
```

and (if you have written) delete header elements(Action, ReplyTo, To, MessageID)

```
SOAPHeaderElement actionElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Action"));
actionElement.setMustUnderstand(true);
String action = (String) messageContext.get("javax.xml.ws.soap.http.soapaction.uri");
actionElement.addTextNode(action);

SOAPHeaderElement replyToElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "ReplyTo"));
SOAPElement addressElement = replyToElement.addChildElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing","Address"));
addressElement.addTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous");

SOAPHeaderElement toElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "To"));
toElement.setMustUnderstand(true);
String endpoint = (String) messageContext.get("javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address");
toElement.addTextNode(endpoint);

SOAPHeaderElement messageIdElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "MessageID"));
messageIdElement.addTextNode("uuid:" +UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved a little bit about it

I received the first error that was --Missing WS-Addressing header--

I find the solve this link: http://informatictips.blogspot.com.tr/2013/09/using-message-handler-to-alter-soap.html

I received the second error that was --can't add a header when one is already present--

I find the solve this link: [SEVERE: SAAJ0120: Can't add a header when one is already present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058752/severe-saaj0120-cant-add-a-header-when-one-is-already-present)

Now I received the third error that was --java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError--

I could not find a solution to this error